# exception while thread is throwing error in scoket c++ windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, exception

i am creating client sever application in windows using socket and i want to throw exception at run time from thread if any problem occur but i am getting error for throw statement.

```
    //create thread in cpp file
    CreateThread(NULL,0,startServer,this,0,NULL);

        //thread in header file
            static unsigned long __stdcall startServer(void *i_SocketTransportServer)
           {
                           ((SocketTransportServer*)i_SocketTransportServer)->StartServerThread(((SocketTransportServer *)i_SocketTransportServer)->m_socketServer);
                return 0;
           }

        //and StartServerThread is function called by thread
         // SocketTransportServer is inner class of  RMLThinTransport
            void RMLThinTransport::SocketTransportServer::StartServerThread(SOCKET i_socketServer)
            {
                m_socketAccept=NULL;
                while(true)
                {
                    Sleep(20);
                    if(m_canAcceptMore)
                    {
                        m_canAcceptMore=false;
                        if(!m_isRunning)
                        {
                                break;
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            m_socketAccept=accept(m_socketServer,NULL,NULL);
                            if(m_socketAccept==INVALID_SOCKET)
                            {
                                int lastError=WSAGetLastError();
                                closesocket(m_socketAccept);
                                                                                                                            SocketExceptions                                        
 exceptionInAcceptAtServer;
                                  exceptionInAcceptAtServer.detectErrorAccept(&lastError);

throw exceptionInAcceptAtServer;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //_LOG("Client connected",EventTypeInfo) ;
                                OutputDebugStringW(L"client connected.....");
                                /* If client connected then setClinetCout value 1 */
                                setClientCount(1);
                                m_ClientSockets.push_back(m_socketAccept);
                                CreateThread(NULL,0,receiveDataAtServer,this,0,NULL);
                            }

                        }
                        catch(SocketExceptions& i_exceptionInAcceptAtServer)
                        {   

                            /*OutputDebugStringW(L"Can't accept client In Exception. ."); */
    throw i_exceptionInAcceptAtServer;//getting runtime error from here

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

now i want to throw error when server close but i am getting run time error. so is there any way so i can get error in my main function.sorry but i am new in c++ so please help me. and error is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that *throws* the exception is not the problem; it's the lack of any code to *catch* the exception that's the problem. The application is terminating because nothing is catching the exception you're throwing; you must ensure that something is going to catch it. Your `startServer` method -- the thread procedure -- must catch the exception, and cleanly exit the thread.

Comment: i want to catch exception not in thread but out side of this thread.

Comment: You can't do that, exceptions don't travel from one thread to another. They unwind the stack of that single thread, and if they hit the top without being caught, your application is terminated. What you could do is catch the exception, and in your catch block use some other mechanism to communicate the problem to the rest of the application.

Comment: Catch the exception on the thread, then transfer it somewhere else by some means you define. (e.g., send a message to your main thread.)

Comment: ok i will try to do it, but  if you have any related example than please tell me. thank you